# Multiple object sets per type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to scaffold the UserController and Views for Users. At first, I would receive errors when scaffolding the controller saying: "Multiple object sets per type are not supported." (This had to do with ApplicationUser and User)
I am trying to scaffold the controller in Areas/Admin.

Then I followed a post at StackOverflow saying to rename the ApplicationUser class to User, which resulted in lots of errors. I changed all of the references to ApplicationUser to User, but I still got the same error.
I changed back to ApplicationUser, tried scaffolding it again, in Controllers (instead of in Areas/Admin). That seemed to work, until I ran the application. It gives me the exact same error.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ImpHer.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImpHer.Models.Project> Projects { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImpHer.Models.Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImpHer.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is `IdentityModels.cs`, who can help me?

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Unable to retrive metadata for 'Models.ApplicationUser'. Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The objects sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Models.ApplicationUser'.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted `public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ImpHer.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers {get;set;}` from `EntityModels.cs`.
Then in `UsersController.cs`, I replaces ApplicationUser with Users everywhere.

This did the trick!

Comment: The only necessary part was getting rid of the `DbSet` that the scaffold added. This appears to be a bug in the scaffold that fails to recognize that `ApplicationUser` already has a `DbSet` by virtue of being the type argument for `IdentityDbContext<>`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Ah, alright, so you're saying I should use `ApplicationUser`? Or is there no difference?

Comment: There's no difference really. I changed mine to just `User` because `ApplicationUser` felt obtuse. I'm just pointing out that that step is no required to fix the issue, in case someone else stumbles upon this answer with the same problem.